# ValueError: `axis` must be fewer than the number of dimensions (1)

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn

i would like to show my trained model in a confusion matrix but if I run my method im getting a error on this code `ytrue = np.argmax(y_test, axis=1).tolist()`:

> raise ValueError(f"`axis` must be fewer than the number of dimensions ({ndim})")
> ValueError: `axis` must be fewer than the number of dimensions (1)

What is wron in my code?

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
X = df.drop(['Rin'], axis=1)
y = df['Rin']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=.2)


model = Sequential()
model.add
...

model.save('tfmodel.h5')

model.load_weights('tfmodel.h5')

yhat = model.predict(X_test)
ytrue = np.argmax(y_test, axis=1).tolist()
yhat = np.argmax(yhat, axis=1).tolist()

print(confusion_matrix(ytrue, yhat))
```

Comment: your targets are already 1d, no need to call argmax on them. they're not a probability matrix. `ytrue = y_test.tolist()`

Comment: @NicolasGervais if I use your solution by changing it into `ytrue = y_test.tolist()`and `yhat = yhat.tolist()` I'm getting a another error message `ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multiclass and continuous-multioutput targets`

Comment: change your targets to integers `ytrue = y_test.astype(int).tolist()`

Comment: Thx ive got it.

Answer (score 0):

From comments

> Targets are `1d`, no need to call `argmax` on them. they're
> not a probability matrix.
>
> After changing the targets to integers `ytrue = y_test.astype(int).tolist()` issue was resolved
>
> (Paraphrased from Nicolas Gervais)